# Can't scrape the links to next pages when using xPath selectors, returns empty. (Using Scrapy)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy and trying to scrape [this](http://pivdenoptika.com.ua/catalog/s_o_u_l_) url, when I request any data about the products on the page I get it out. But the div with the paginator class and id=paginator1 is returned as empty even though it is a table with references to next pages. I have tried using xPath selectors for the table and css selectors, but both return empty. 
This is what I tried, using css

`In [29]: response.css('span a::attr(href)').extract()
Out[29]: 
['/registration/formregistration/new',
 '/',
 '/catalog/solntsezaschitnye_ochki',
 'http://wezom.com.ua/prodvizhenie']`

and

`In [31]: response.xpath('//*[@id="paginator1"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span')
Out[31]: []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination is generated using JavaScript, as you can see in the HTML:

```
<div class="paginator" id="paginator1"></div>
<div class="paginator_pages">Страниц: 14</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*pag1 = new Paginator("id div", vsego stranic, kol-vo na stranice, tekuchay stranica, "url");*/
pag1 = new Paginator("paginator1", 14, 10, 1, "/catalog/s_o_u_l_/page/", "/catalog/s_o_u_l_");
</script>
```

You can extract all of the relevant information out of the `<script>` block:

```
import ast

script = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "paginator1")]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
paginator = script.splitlines()[1].strip().split('new Paginator')[1].rstrip(';')

paginatorHolderId, pagesTotal, pagesSpan, pageCurrent, baseUrl = ast.literal_eval(paginator)
```

You can then build the pagination URLs according to the logic in [the pagination script](http://pivdenoptika.com.ua/js/paginator3000.js) (or just see what the URLs look like).

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the actual html source (`response.text`), you will see the following:

```html
<div class="paginator" id="paginator1"></div>
<div class="paginator_pages">Страниц: 14</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*pag1 = new Paginator("id div", vsego stranic, kol-vo na stranice, tekuchay stranica, "url");*/
pag1 = new Paginator("paginator1", 14, 10, 1, "/catalog/s_o_u_l_/page/", "/catalog/s_o_u_l_");
</script>
```

As you can see, the div is indeed empty, and being populated through javascript.

You have two options to get those links:

1. Generate them yourself (should be fairly easy)
2. Use something to run the javascript for you (e.g. a headless browser)